# Entity Framework Core - Include nested list inside list

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I include an inner list, which is inside another list, in a Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 query?

This is what I tried without success:

```
clase = repClase.ListQueryable(
    //Specification
    new ApplicationCore.Specifications.ClaseFilterByIdAndIdArticuloWithIncludesSpecification(idClase, idArticuloParam)
)
.Include(c => c.ReferenciasConstructor)
.ThenInclude(rc => rc.Select(rc1 => rc1.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor))
.FirstOrDefault();
```

And the error it throws:
"*The property expression 'rc => {from ReferenciaConstructor rc1 in rc select [rc1].ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.*".

Classes:

```
[Table("Clases", Schema = "public")]
public class Clase
{

    ...

    [InverseProperty("Clase")]
    public IList<ReferenciaConstructor> ReferenciasConstructor { get; set; }

}

[Table("ReferenciasConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaConstructor
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    //JOIN TABLE
    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaConstructor")]
    public IList<ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor> ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

}


//JOIN TABLE
[Table("ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor {

    [Key]
    public int IdReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaFabricante")]
    public ReferenciaFabricante ReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int IdReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaConstructor")]
    public ReferenciaConstructor ReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As stated by the error, the `expression` in `Include(expression)` cannot be an arbitrary expression. Use `Select` instead.

Comment: `.ThenInclude(rc => rc.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor)` - see the duplicate question why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Include` to select purpose. Just `select` the desired properties.

```
clase = repClase.ListQueryable(
        //Specification
        new ApplicationCore.Specifications.ClaseFilterByIdAndIdArticuloWithIncludesSpecification(idClase, idArticuloParam)
    )
    .Include(c => c.ReferenciasConstructor)
    .SelectMany(rc => rc.ReferenciasConstructor.Select(rc1 => rc1.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```