# EF Core include list of list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a very simple model.
the main class, Recipe, contains a list of RecipeItem. Every RecipeItem has a list of RecipeItemComponents.

Using the Entity Framework context, I can do this:

```
var ret = await _context.Recipes
.Include(x => x.RecipeItems)
.ToListAsync();
```

This code returns The recipes with the RecipeItems, but for every RecipeItems I have not RecipeItemsComponent list.
It makes sense since I'm not including those, but I'm, not sure no how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Use `ThenInclude` after `Include`

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277087/entity-framework-core-include-nested-list-inside-list

Comment: As @RudreshaParameshappa said, you are looking for `.Include(x => x.RecipeItems).ThenInclude(ri => ri.RecipeItemsComponent)`

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa It is what I tried before writing the post, but 'ri' in your example is a list of RecipeItems, so it doesn't allow me to do ri.RecipeItemsComponent

Comment: @ff8mania visual studio doesn't provide IntelliSense for `ThenInclude`. Just type your collection property. Then it will get updated.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa in this way is not even going to build...

Answer (score 6):

Here is my working code sample

Models

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child1> Child1s { get; set; }
}

 public class Child1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child2> Child2s { get; set; }
}

public class Child2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Child1Id { get; set; }
    public Child1 Child1 { get; set; }
}
```

In the DB context class

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(x => x.Child1s).WithOne(x => x.Parent).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child1>().HasMany(x => x.Child2s).WithOne(x => x.Child1).HasForeignKey(x => x.Child1Id);

        this.InitialData(modelBuilder);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected void InitialData(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasData(new Parent[]
        {
            new Parent
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Parent 1",
            }
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child1>().HasData(new Child1[]
        {
            new Child1
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Child 1 1",
                ParentId = 1,
            }
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child2>().HasData(new Child2[]
        {
            new Child2
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Child 2 1",
                Child1Id = 1
            }
        });
    }

    public DbSet<Parent> Parent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child1> Child1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child2> Child2s { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class ParentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestDbContext _context;

    public ParentsController(TestDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var parent = await _context.Parent
            .Include(x=>x.Child1s).ThenInclude(x=>x.Child2s)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(parent);
    }
}
```

Here is the output
[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can't use the strongly typed extension methods to include everything. In some cases you need to use a string:

```
.Include("RecipeItems.RecipeItemsComponents")
```

For those curious, the documentation for this overload is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_Include__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_String_

Comment: Yes it does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#code-try-9

Comment: From EF Core 1.0 onwards I believe as well.